# 2sxc cms.run edit with prefill

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm trying to use prefill in public forms edit with this:

```
$2sxc.cms.run(
    tag,
    {
        action: "edit", 
        entityId: eid,
        prefill: {
            LastEditedBy: "@Dnn.User.Username",
            LastEditedOn: "@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"
        }
    }
);
```

It does not return errors, but the prefill does not work. Is the syntax wrong or the edit action does not allow prefill?

Comment: edit usually doesn't expect a prefill, so you may want to try `new` instead.

Comment: Note that Entities have an `Owner` property which you should be able to use to find the user, and also a `Created` for the creation date, so you may not need all of this.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to fix the code I copied. It's the last update user and date I need.

Comment: So last update is property "Modified" - I believe we added that about 2 months ago...

Comment: But I do believe that the modified user isn't going to work, since I think prefill is only respected on new...